# Interacts with QT using web

Tags: qt, web

I need to transfer data from a QML project to the web and I don't know how to do with that.

I have a QT client and I want to make the industrial data update on the website at the same time. If I need to create a HTTP client based on QT in the project? I am so confused.

And I also need to use web to send message to my QT project, how my backend work with? A micro-service?
If my QML project needs to add a HTTP server?

Sorry for my stupid question but I have been thinking for a week.

Comment: I want to interact with QT using a external web.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to upload the data to the web server, through the suitable API / web page.
If it's already possible to add data manually, then you can do the same programmatically with Qt, through HTTP requests.
If not, you'll need to get this interface done, and it's probably beyond your current question.